# MySQL Exclusive JOIN with multiple values for one column

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

I have the following structure in MySQL:

```
business
-------------
id
name


service
-------------
id
name


business_service
-----------------
business_id
service_id
```

I want to select the business that have not one but all the specified services. If I do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM business LEFT JOIN business_service ON business_service.business_id = business.id WHERE business_service.service_id IN (1,2,3)
```

It will return the business that have the service 1, 2 or 3. I want to retrive the business that have the three.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that table `business_service` has no duplicate rows (which you can and should ensure via a `primary key` or `unique` constraint), and that `business_service.service_id` never take a `null` value (which you should also enforce via a constraint), you can approach the problem like this:

```
select b.id, b.name
from (
    select business_id
    from business_service
    group by business_id
    having count(*) = (select count(*) from service)
  ) bs
  join business b
    on b.id = bs.business_id
```

If you want to identify those businesses having only a specific subset of the services, then you can take a similar approach:

```
select b.id, b.name
from (
    select business_id
    from business_service
    where service_id in (1, 2, 3)
    group by business_id
    having count(*) = 3
  ) bs
  join business b
    on b.id = bs.business_id
```

In each case, the inline view identifies those businesses (by ID) that have the expected number of services -- same number of services as table `service` overall in the first case, or the number of service ids in the filter in the second case.  The main query just joins that to table `business` to associate the business names with those IDs.  If you only need the business IDs then the inline views could be used standalone for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks! And if the `service` table contains 10 records for example, and I want to retrieve the `business` that have services 1, 2 and 3 ?

Comment: @gsobrevilla, sorry, I see I missed slightly, but a small variation on my original query will select those businesses having all the services in a specified subset.  I have updated my answer with an example.